# How to build runnable apk with aapt2?

Tags: android, aapt2

I have a simple android [project](http://download.illuzor.com/code/project.zip).
This commands compile resources and build apk without dex:

```
aapt2 compile project/res/values/strings.xml project/res/layout/activity_main.xml -o project/compiled_res

aapt2 link -o project/apk/unsigned_app.apk -I sdk/platforms/android-28/android.jar --manifest project/src/AndroidManifest.xml -R project/compiled_res/*.flat --java project/src --auto-add-overlay
```

Quote from [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/aapt2#link):

> However, the generated APK does not contain DEX bytecode and is
>   unsigned
>   ...
>   you can use other command line tools, such as d8 to
>   compile Java bytecode into DEX bytecode and apksigner to sign your
>   APK.

Ok. I can:

```
d8 project/compiled_classes/com/illuzor/buildtest/*.class --output project/dex
```

But how to pack this dex to apk? aapt2 can`t recognize classes.dex:

[image]

I can just add classes.dex to my apk by zipping:

```
zip -uj project/apk/unsigned_app.apk project/dex/classes.dex
```

And it works after aligning and signing. But must be another way, more proper.

Answer (score 2):

I'm looking for a proper way too. But I have no luck even it is 2019 now, and I searched everywhere, for days.

I guess `aapt add` will get the job done, but your solution with `zip` is not bad.

Hope `aapt` won't be deprecated soon, or `aapt2` should get enhanced before that happens.